# Image div set to height: 100% but not expanding to 100% - trying to avoid 100vh

Tags: css

I am having an issue with my image div not expanding to `height: 100%`.

`html`, `body`, and `wrapper` are set to `height: 100%`.

The code below is what I am currently using:

```
.blogimgcont {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}

.blogimgcont img{
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}
```

100vh does make the image take up the entire vertical height but I am afraid of running into cross-browser compatibility issues using it.

Can anyone pinpoint why height: 100% is not working?

please view http://protein.guru/ for clarification

Edit:

I decided to use 100vh anyway - thank you for the answers

Comment: if .blogimgcont has no parents with a width specified , then you have 100% of nothing ;)

Comment: @BinaryGhost if .blogimgcont is child of body, body needs an height set ... else there no valid value to inherit and pass to img ... basic CSS rules nothing more or less ;)

Comment: You won't be able to achieve the effect you're looking for with just `height: 100%`. The issue, and you can see this if you inspect your parent element, is that setting height to a percentage does not set it relative to the height of the viewport, but to its container. However, since there is no explicit height set on its container, it assumes the height of its children. This means that you can set your image to 100% of it's parent container, but the parent is the wrong size (not 100% of the viewport, but 100% of its children).

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
.blogimgcont {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```